# How to understand this detailed multithreading and anonymous class related code?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }) 
    {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("world");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Simply I get "world" with this. Why it can be written in this manner? What is the first `run()` method for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (contrived) code passes an instance of an anonymous `Runnable` class to an instance of an anonymous `Thread` class that overrides its usual implementation of `run()`.

It's becomes (a little) clearer if you refactor it:

```
// The runnable instance
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
};

// Anonymous Thread class with a custom run() method
new Thread(runnable) {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}.start();
```

The `Runnable` passed to the `Thread`, which would be executed by the thread's `start()` method, is ignored because the `Thread` object is also an instance of an anonymous class with a custom implementation of its `run()` method, which is hard-coded to print `"world"`.

Comment: Giving an equivalent refactored code is my expection here. Thanks. Still one thing unclear: `Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){}`. I know it is to instantiate an instance just like `ClassA classA = new ClassA()` but ClassA is a class while `Runnable` is an interface. How can an object created via an interface? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code creates an instance of an anonymous sub-class of `Thread` and then starts that thread.

That sub-class overrides `Thread`'s `run()` method with a method that prints `"world"`.

The first `run()` method is part of an anonymous implementation of the `Runnable` interface which is passed to the constructor of the `Thread` instance. That implementation is ignored, since your `Thread` implementation overrides `run()`.

The `Runnable` instance passed to the thread constructor is only executed (when the thread starts) if the `Thread`'s `run()` method is not overridden.

Comment: "The first run() method is part of an anonymous implementation of the Runnable interface _which_ is.. " Does the "_which_" refer to the anonymous implementation? I think the "anonymous implementation" is the instance created by the anonymous class which implements Runnable interface. Is it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden the `run` method which prints `hello` with the one which prints `world`. This happened because in your code you have extended the Thread class with an anonymous class which overrode the run method, therefore the `Runnable` parameter's `run` is never called. You can update the code to use `super.run()` to call the runnable method from the original class.

Here is your code with the changes:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }) {
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            System.out.println("world");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: There's no keyword `extends`, so is this a special way of inheritance?

Comment: Yes, this is a special form of inheritance since you create an anonymous class. See this link for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread` class defines `run()` in this way :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

It invokes the `run()` method of the `Runnable` instance (`target` field of `Thread`)if this field is not `null`.

So when you create an anonymous class of `Thread` that overrides this method in this way:

```
new Thread(...) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}
```

The Thread `run()` method of the anonymous instance doesn't rely any longer on the `target` field to run the `Runnable` instance.
It execute only this code :

```
System.out.println("world");
```

So the `Runnable` instance passed to the constructor of `Thread` is totally ignored by `run()`:

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```